# Aura Workspace API methods inside VF not working. How to close a previously open sub tab using Workspace API on a VF container

Tags: visualforce, aura

I'm using aura within VF because custom list buttons don't support aura yet.  I'm launching the vf using url apex/vfpagehereetc... to launch that VF container then the aura inside will fire event for createRecord. I want to close the previously opened blank VF sub tab once createevent has been fired. Workspace api component is visible on javascript and isValid equals true but the methods in it are not returning the promises not even errors. The code is not complete here because the rest are working fine, the workspace api is detectable. Any ideas why and/or how to fix?

[image][image]

```
<aura:component controller="ACRCloneActionCompController">
    <aura:registerEvent name="acrCloneEvt" type="c:ACRCloneAppEvt" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="acctId" type="String" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute
    name="relationId"
    type="String"
    access="private"
  ></aura:attribute>

  <aura:attribute
    name="isLoaded"
    type="Boolean"
    access="private"
    default="false"
  ></aura:attribute>

  <aura:attribute
    name="parentRecordId"
    type="String"
    access="private"
  ></aura:attribute>
    <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="small" aura:id="theSpinner" />

    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />


</aura:component>
```

Helperjs:

```
    loadTabContext: function(component) {
        // will return valid
        console.log('DBG in loadTabContext', component.find("workspace"));

        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI
        .getFocusedTabInfo()
        .then(function(response) {
            // never goes inside this
            console.log('DBg focused tab: ');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // neither this
            console.log('DBG error in tab: ');
        });
        // skips directly here and doesn't go back to the promises
        console.log('DBG after workspace');
      },
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">




<apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
    var url = window.location.href;
    console.log('DBG url: ', url);
    var urlsplit = url.split('?acctid='); 

    var acctRecordId;// = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";

    console.log('DBG acctRecordId: ', urlsplit);

    if (urlsplit[1] != null && urlsplit[1].charAt(15) === '&') {     
        acctRecordId = urlsplit[1].substring(0,15);
    }
    console.log('DBG acctRecordId: ', acctRecordId);

    var visualForceFunction = function(event) {
            console.log('DBG app event data: ');
            if (sforce && sforce.one) {
                console.log('DBG inside sforce');
                sforce.one.createRecord("AccountContactRelation", null,
                    {
                        "ContactId" : event.getParam("ContactId"),
                        "JobTitle__c" : event.getParam("JobTitle__c"),
                        "Language__c" : event.getParam("Language__c"),
                        "CommunicationMethod__c" : event.getParam("CommunicationMethod__c"),
                        "Function__c" : event.getParam("Function__c"),
                        "Telephone__c" : event.getParam("Telephone__c"),
                        "MobilePhone__c" : event.getParam("MobilePhone__c"),
                        "Fax__c" : event.getParam("Fax__c"),
                        "Email__c" : event.getParam("Email__c"),
                        "SafetyResponsible__c" : event.getParam("SafetyResponsible__c"),
                        "EnvironmentResponsible__c" : event.getParam("EnvironmentResponsible__c"),
                        "PricingResponsible__c" : event.getParam("PricingResponsible__c"),
                        "QuotationRepairResponsible__c" : event.getParam("QuotationRepairResponsible__c"),
                        "FMMainContact__c" : event.getParam("FMMainContact__c"),
                        "FleetExchange__c" : event.getParam("FleetExchange__c"),
                        "ONTrack__c" : event.getParam("ONTrack__c"),
                        "IsDirect" : false
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    $Lightning.use("c:acrCloneActionApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:acrCloneActionComp", { acctId : acctRecordId }, "lightning", function() {
            $A.eventService.addHandler({ "event": "c:ACRCloneAppEvt", "handler" : visualForceFunction});
        });
    }); 



        </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is a known limitation. The `workspaceAPI` is not supported in Lightning Out. What are you actually trying to accomplish? What's your end goal?

Comment: I want to close the middle sub tab in the pic i attached. its the VF container that launched the Create Event from the lightning component. correct me if im wrong but if its not supported, why when i debug the workspace, it shows the the commands on the screenshot above ? or maybe just the commands doesn't work. If I can't use workspace api to close the VF sub tab, any other suggestion if there's any way we can close that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the introduction of [lightning:isUrlAddressable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation), the URLs have been normalised in a readable format for both `setting` and `getting`.

You can give direct URL of lightning component which has implemented `lightning:isUrlAddressable`. Below for example:

[image]

As you see, you can also pass URL parameters `c__att1` and `c__att2`.

Consuming the attributes in JS:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
    let state = component.get("v.pageReference").state;
    console.log('STATE => ',state.c__att1, state.c__att2);
}
```

and in COMPONENT file directly:

```
<div class="slds-theme_default">
    state - {!v.pageReference.state.c__att1}
</div>
```

Comment: yeah but its almost the same approach as above. it will open a sub tab to launch the POC_AURA, then i need the force:createEvent to launch the standard event to create record which will also launch another subtab. my issue is to close the previously opened subtab.

Comment: In this approach `worksapceAPI` will work because you are in lightning experience and not visualforce

Comment: ok will try and let you know

Comment: i'm encountering: This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app. I tried both component and application aura, and implemented flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes. any idea ?

Comment: yeah thank you for answering that it needs c__ both at the beginning of the comp name and attributes. forgot about that